# Auto scroll does not work as desired

Tags: jquery

I was looking at an example here

http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bw6Xw/6/

```
div.on('mousemove', function(e) {
    var cPointY = e.pageY,
        dP = ((cPointY / wrapHeight));
    div.scrollTop((listHeight * dP) - wrapScreenHeight);

});
```

I tried to replicate the same here http://jsfiddle.net/bw6Xw/188/ but it does not work.

Any reasons why?

Comment: Because you're using a select rather than a list

Comment: Plus in javascript is looking for UL, when there is no `ul`

Comment: how I can convert the example to work in a select?

Comment: @Thomasmkov: Check my updated answer..Works for me now, no hard coded values

Answer (score 0):

I did something but I have a hard coded value for height of select...
Check this out:

http://jsfiddle.net/bw6Xw/193/

```
var div = $('#lstBox1'),
wrapScreenHeight = div.height(),    
wrapHeight = div.outerHeight(),
listHeight = wrapScreenHeight + (wrapHeight * 2);

div.on('mousemove', function(e) {
    var cPointY = e.pageY,
    dP = ((cPointY / wrapHeight));
    div.scrollTop((listHeight * dP) - wrapScreenHeight);

});
```

Comment: Thanks @ani but as you can see in the example, it does not scroll as smooth as the original example. It stops scrolling halfway. Why do you think this is happening?

Comment: Change  listHeight = 4 * wrapScreenHeight; I'll update my answer too.

Comment: yes the scrolling is smooth however the list shows a bunch of empty items when it scrolls to the bottom. Did you also observe the same?